# Passing handles to subfunction when using `ButtonDownFcn` in Matlab gui

Tags: matlab, callback, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I need to process an image based on where the user is clicking using Matlab Gui. I have found examples which suggest to use the `ButtonDownFcn` like this:

```
function buttonSelectSuperpixels_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
h = handles.myCanvas;
set(h,'ButtonDownFcn',@position_and_button);
```

and then process the clicked points in the subfunction `position_and_button` like this:

```
function position_and_button(hObject,eventdata)
Position = get( ancestor(hObject,'axes'), 'CurrentPoint' );
Button = get( ancestor(hObject,'figure'), 'SelectionType' );
```

However I would need to process some other variables in that last subfunction. Is it possible to pass the `handles` variable to `position_and_button` and also update it?

I tried to just pass `handles` as an argument but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What if you change the set to  `set(h,'ButtonDownFcn',@(x,y)position_and_button(x,y,handles));` and then update the subfunction to accept handles also, just keep in mind that the handles structure will always be the one as seen in the subfunction `buttonSelectSuperpixels_Callback`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the `handles` struct to your callback by adding it as an input using either an anonymous function

```
set(h, 'ButtonDownFcn', @(src, evnt)position_and_button(src, evnt, handles))
```

Or a cell array

```
set(h, 'ButtonDownFcn', {@position_and_button, handles})
```

The issue though, is that MATLAB passes variables *by value* rather than by reference. So when you define these callbacks, they will make a *copy* of `handles` as it looks when the callback is created. It is this *copy* that will be passed to the other function. Additionally, any changes that you make to `handles` within your callback are made to *yet another copy* and no other function will ever see these changes.

To avoid this behavior, you can retrieve the `handles` struct from the `guidata`  within your callback (ensuring you have the most up-to-date version). Then, if you make any changes to it, you would then need to save the `guidata` after these changes and all other functions will be able to see these changes.

```
function position_and_button(src, evnt)
    % Get the handles struct
    handles = guidata(src);

    % Now use handles struct however you want including changing variables
    handles.variable2 = 2;

    % Now save the changes
    guidata(src, handles)

    % Update the CData of the image rather than creating a new one
    set(src, 'CData', newimage)
end
```

In this case, you would only need to specify the default two inputs to the callback function.

Comment: For the first method it's worth noting that because the callback is using a copy of `handles`, the value of passed to the callback will be as it was when you set the callback.

Comment: @excaza Yea definitely. I had that in my original answer but had taken it out. I'll put it back in.

Comment: Also `guidata` looks for the parent figure internally, so the `ancestor` call isn't strictly necessary.

Comment: This seems to work. However I still have the problem that the image seems to be clickable only once. I guess the `guidata(src,handles`) function is somehow destroying the `ButtonDownFcn` listener, any idea how to keep the listener going? (and thanks a lot for your help so far)

Comment: @mcExchange That should not affect anything. Maybe show us the contents of `position_and_button`? It is possible that you are removing the plot object?

Comment: Yes. I basically need the user to click on some superpixels and they are highlighted with some color. So after each click `h = imshow` is called. Is it possible to do this without overwriting the image handle?

Comment: @mcExchange Yes. Do you have a handle to the `imshow` object stored in `handles`?

Comment: @mcExchange I've added a little line of code at the end of the example above that shows how to update the image without creating a new one.

Comment: Rejoice :D. It's working now. Thanks a lot! You saved me quite some hours ;)